# Prometheus on GKE - unable to attach PVC to Prometheus (deployed using Prometheus operator)

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, prometheus-operator, kubernetes-pvc

I have a Prometheus installation on GKE, installed using Prometheus Operator - and this is working fine.
I'm trying to attach Persistent Disk to the prometheus install .. from what i understand - Prometheus install has Ephemeral storage, and therefore if the pod restarts that the metrics are lost.

Here are the yaml's used :

```
Prometheus.yaml (kind: Prometheus)

apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  labels:
    app: strimzi
spec:
  replicas: 1
  retention: 168h
  serviceAccountName: prometheus-server
  podMonitorSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: strimzi
  serviceMonitorSelector: {}
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 400Mi
  enableAdminAPI: false
  ruleSelector:
    matchLabels:
      role: alert-rules
      app: strimzi
  alerting:
    alertmanagers:
    - namespace: monitoring
      name: alertmanager
      port: alertmanager
  additionalScrapeConfigs:
    name: additional-scrape-configs
    key: prometheus-additional.yaml
  volumeMounts:
    - name: prometheus-storage
      mountPath: /prometheus-pvc
  storage:
    volumeClaimTemplate:
      metadata:
        labels:
            app: strimzi
        name: prometheus-storage
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 50Gi
        storageClassName: prometheus-ssd



Storageclass.yaml :

allowVolumeExpansion: true
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: prometheus-ssd
parameters:
  type: pd-ssd
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

when i run the above 2 yamls, the StorageClass, PVC get created .. however the pod is not starting up.

```
(base) Karans-MacBook-Pro:prometheus-grafana karanalang$ kubectl get pvc -n monitoring
NAME                                         STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS     AGE
prometheus-storage-prometheus-prometheus-0   Bound    pvc-788c6356-f435-4889-96d7-3ef6f3dbbbd3   50Gi       RWO            prometheus-ssd   11m


(base) Karans-MacBook-Pro:prometheus-grafana karanalang$ kubectl get sc | grep prometheus-ssd  
prometheus-ssd       kubernetes.io/gce-pd    Delete          Immediate              true                   11m

(base) Karans-MacBook-Pro:prometheus-grafana karanalang$ kc describe pod/prometheus-prometheus-0 -n monitoring
Name:         prometheus-prometheus-0
Namespace:    monitoring
Priority:     0
Node:         gke-prometheus-test-default-pool-b5bb218b-q4p8/10.142.15.206
Start Time:   Sat, 08 Oct 2022 16:15:58 -0700
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/instance=prometheus
              app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=prometheus-operator
              app.kubernetes.io/name=prometheus
              app.kubernetes.io/version=2.32.1
              controller-revision-hash=prometheus-prometheus-7974d4549f
              operator.prometheus.io/name=prometheus
              operator.prometheus.io/shard=0
              prometheus=prometheus
              statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=prometheus-prometheus-0
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/default-container: prometheus
Status:       Running
IP:           10.100.2.5
IPs:
  IP:           10.100.2.5
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/prometheus-prometheus
Init Containers:
  init-config-reloader:
    Container ID:  containerd://e338786206bcbd56420d40938e8f66246fc8f81420e777bab62b865505f625b8
    Image:         quay.io/prometheus-operator/prometheus-config-reloader:v0.53.1
    Image ID:      quay.io/prometheus-operator/prometheus-config-reloader@sha256:72f4616b02188261f433019734eb25dc60338299f644b26cc1b2d701dd5d888e
    Port:          8080/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Command:
      /bin/prometheus-config-reloader
    Args:
      --watch-interval=0
      --listen-address=:8080
      --config-file=/etc/prometheus/config/prometheus.yaml.gz
      --config-envsubst-file=/etc/prometheus/config_out/prometheus.env.yaml
      --watched-dir=/etc/prometheus/rules/prometheus-prometheus-rulefiles-0
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Sat, 08 Oct 2022 16:16:07 -0700
      Finished:     Sat, 08 Oct 2022 16:16:07 -0700
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  50Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  50Mi
    Environment:
      POD_NAME:  prometheus-prometheus-0 (v1:metadata.name)
      SHARD:     0
    Mounts:
      /etc/prometheus/config from config (rw)
      /etc/prometheus/config_out from config-out (rw)
      /etc/prometheus/rules/prometheus-prometheus-rulefiles-0 from prometheus-prometheus-rulefiles-0 (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-zkqm7 (ro)
Containers:
  prometheus:
    Container ID:  containerd://09a66380dafbfdd6a1e3c8aa230ea29b8945ad03ff81a5bc2b0a38cab40d0db0
    Image:         quay.io/prometheus/prometheus
    Image ID:      quay.io/prometheus/prometheus@sha256:4748e26f9369ee7270a7cd3fb9385c1adb441c05792ce2bce2f6dd622fd91d38
    Port:          9090/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Args:
      --web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles
      --web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries
      --config.file=/etc/prometheus/config_out/prometheus.env.yaml
      --storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus
      --storage.tsdb.retention.time=168h
      --web.enable-lifecycle
      --web.route-prefix=/
      --web.config.file=/etc/prometheus/web_config/web-config.yaml
    State:       Waiting
      Reason:    CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:  Terminated
      Reason:    Error
      Message:   ts=2022-10-08T23:17:48.449Z caller=main.go:543 level=info msg="Starting Prometheus Server" mode=server version="(version=2.39.1, branch=HEAD, revision=dcd6af9e0d56165c6f5c64ebbc1fae798d24933a)"
ts=2022-10-08T23:17:48.449Z caller=main.go:548 level=info build_context="(go=go1.19.2, user=root@273d60c69592, date=20221007-15:57:09)"
ts=2022-10-08T23:17:48.449Z caller=main.go:549 level=info host_details="(Linux 5.10.127+ #1 SMP Fri Jul 8 00:39:24 UTC 2022 x86_64 prometheus-prometheus-0 (none))"
ts=2022-10-08T23:17:48.449Z caller=main.go:550 level=info fd_limits="(soft=1048576, hard=1048576)"
ts=2022-10-08T23:17:48.449Z caller=main.go:551 level=info vm_limits="(soft=unlimited, hard=unlimited)"
ts=2022-10-08T23:17:48.450Z caller=query_logger.go:91 level=error component=activeQueryTracker msg="Error opening query log file" file=/prometheus/queries.active err="open /prometheus/queries.active: permission denied"
panic: Unable to create mmap-ed active query log

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/prometheus/prometheus/promql.NewActiveQueryTracker({0x7ffc5eee0dc4, 0xb}, 0x14, {0x3aba480, 0xc0005f0780})
  /app/promql/query_logger.go:121 +0x3cd
main.main()
  /app/cmd/prometheus/main.go:605 +0x6773

      Exit Code:    2
      Started:      Sat, 08 Oct 2022 16:17:48 -0700
      Finished:     Sat, 08 Oct 2022 16:17:48 -0700
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  4
    Requests:
      memory:     400Mi
    Readiness:    http-get http://:web/-/ready delay=0s timeout=3s period=5s #success=1 #failure=3
    Startup:      http-get http://:web/-/ready delay=0s timeout=3s period=15s #success=1 #failure=60
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/prometheus/certs from tls-assets (ro)
      /etc/prometheus/config_out from config-out (ro)
      /etc/prometheus/rules/prometheus-prometheus-rulefiles-0 from prometheus-prometheus-rulefiles-0 (rw)
      /etc/prometheus/web_config/web-config.yaml from web-config (ro,path="web-config.yaml")
      /prometheus from prometheus-storage (rw,path="prometheus-db")
      /prometheus-pvc from prometheus-storage (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-zkqm7 (ro)
  config-reloader:
    Container ID:  containerd://e13e5e5f7b3e339d84d10d43d3aa001ed3a586620e14cd29a06f94cde34bd87e
    Image:         quay.io/prometheus-operator/prometheus-config-reloader:v0.53.1
    Image ID:      quay.io/prometheus-operator/prometheus-config-reloader@sha256:72f4616b02188261f433019734eb25dc60338299f644b26cc1b2d701dd5d888e
    Port:          8080/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Command:
      /bin/prometheus-config-reloader
    Args:
      --listen-address=:8080
      --reload-url=http://localhost:9090/-/reload
      --config-file=/etc/prometheus/config/prometheus.yaml.gz
      --config-envsubst-file=/etc/prometheus/config_out/prometheus.env.yaml
      --watched-dir=/etc/prometheus/rules/prometheus-prometheus-rulefiles-0
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sat, 08 Oct 2022 16:16:11 -0700
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  50Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  50Mi
    Environment:
      POD_NAME:  prometheus-prometheus-0 (v1:metadata.name)
      SHARD:     0
    Mounts:
      /etc/prometheus/config from config (rw)
      /etc/prometheus/config_out from config-out (rw)
      /etc/prometheus/rules/prometheus-prometheus-rulefiles-0 from prometheus-prometheus-rulefiles-0 (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-zkqm7 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  prometheus-storage:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  prometheus-storage-prometheus-prometheus-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  config:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  prometheus-prometheus
    Optional:    false
  tls-assets:
    Type:                Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    SecretName:          prometheus-prometheus-tls-assets-0
    SecretOptionalName:  <nil>
  config-out:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  prometheus-prometheus-rulefiles-0:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      prometheus-prometheus-rulefiles-0
    Optional:  false
  web-config:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  prometheus-prometheus-web-config
    Optional:    false
  kube-api-access-zkqm7:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                    From                     Message
  ----     ------                  ----                   ----                     -------
  Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp       3m3s                   cluster-autoscaler       pod didn't trigger scale-up:
  Warning  FailedScheduling        3m1s (x2 over 3m5s)    default-scheduler        0/3 nodes are available: 3 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.
  Normal   Scheduled               2m59s                  default-scheduler        Successfully assigned monitoring/prometheus-prometheus-0 to gke-prometheus-test-default-pool-b5bb218b-q4p8
  Normal   SuccessfulAttachVolume  2m54s                  attachdetach-controller  AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-788c6356-f435-4889-96d7-3ef6f3dbbbd3"
  Normal   Pulling                 2m52s                  kubelet                  Pulling image "quay.io/prometheus-operator/prometheus-config-reloader:v0.53.1"
  Normal   Created                 2m50s                  kubelet                  Created container init-config-reloader
  Normal   Pulled                  2m50s                  kubelet                  Successfully pulled image "quay.io/prometheus-operator/prometheus-config-reloader:v0.53.1" in 1.151360313s
  Normal   Started                 2m50s                  kubelet                  Started container init-config-reloader
  Normal   Pulled                  2m46s                  kubelet                  Container image "quay.io/prometheus-operator/prometheus-config-reloader:v0.53.1" already present on machine
  Normal   Started                 2m46s                  kubelet                  Started container config-reloader
  Normal   Created                 2m46s                  kubelet                  Created container config-reloader
  Normal   Pulled                  2m46s                  kubelet                  Successfully pulled image "quay.io/prometheus/prometheus" in 3.146973483s
  Normal   Pulled                  2m43s                  kubelet                  Successfully pulled image "quay.io/prometheus/prometheus" in 147.44416ms
  Normal   Started                 2m22s (x3 over 2m46s)  kubelet                  Started container prometheus
  Normal   Created                 2m22s (x3 over 2m46s)  kubelet                  Created container prometheus
  Normal   Pulling                 2m22s (x3 over 2m50s)  kubelet                  Pulling image "quay.io/prometheus/prometheus"
  Normal   Pulled                  2m22s                  kubelet                  Successfully pulled image "quay.io/prometheus/prometheus" in 170.47564ms
  Warning  BackOff                 2m17s (x6 over 2m43s)  kubelet                  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Couple of questions :

The yaml specifies replica: 1, however there are 2 pods created
why is that the case? I was expecting only 1 pod to get created.

what changes do i need in the yaml to get this working ?
How do i debug/fix this.
tia !

Update : seems this is the primary issue

```
ts=2022-10-09T00:24:10.717Z caller=query_logger.go:91 level=error component=activeQueryTracker msg="Error opening query log file" file=/prometheus/queries.active err="open /prometheus/queries.active: permission denied"
panic: Unable to create mmap-ed active query log
```

Update :
Added initContainers to the yaml, where i'm launching busybox and making permission changes to the volumeMount, and it is starting without any errors

```
initContainers:
  - name: permission-fix
    image: busybox
    command: ["chown", "-R", "65534:65534", "/prometheus-pvc"]
    command: ["/bin/chmod","-R","777", "/prometheus-pvc"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: prometheus-storage
      mountPath: /prometheus-pvc
  storage:
    volumeClaimTemplate:
      metadata:
        labels:
            app: strimzi
        name: prometheus-storage
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 50Gi
        storageClassName: prometheus-ssd
```

However, when i logon to the pod, I was expecting to see the folder -> /prometheus-pvc
However, there is no such folder on the pod

Any ideas why ?
tia !

Comment: you have used that folder into init or further into container also ?

Comment: @HarshManvar - didnt understand the question, when i exec into the pod - i'm unable to see folder /prometheus-pvc